# How do I find an anchor element by its href attribute?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to manipulate the following lines using jQuery:

```
<a href="#section-one"><div class="section-dots active-section"></div></a>
<a href="#section-two"><div class="section-dots"></div></a>
<a href="#section-three"><div class="section-dots"></div></a>
<a href="#section-four"><div class="section-dots"></div></a>
```

How can I get the anchor element by an href, for example `#section-one`, and then update the next element with the class `"active-section"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is worded very vaguely, but hopefully this answers it.

> how can I get the element by a href ... i.e. #section-one

```
$('[href="#section-one"]')
```

> and then update the next element class with "active-section"

```
$('[href="#section-one"]').next().addClass('active-section')
```

Comment: How do I add the class to the DIV within the <a href element, I didn't realize that the <dIV wasn't Next but actually part of the <a href

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel `$('[href="#section-one"]').find('.section-dots').addClass('active-section')`

Answer (score 0):

```
Something like this should work for you. You may have to alter this code a bit.

$(".active-section").removeClass("active-section");
$( "a[href='#section-one']" ).next().addClass( "active-section" );
```

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

https://api.jquery.com/